# Use filepath of file in assets folder in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, homestead, lottie

I have an external js script (`script.js`) which looks like this:

```
var anim = document.getElementById('bodymovin');

var animData = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: anim,
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path: 'NEED_HELP_HERE',
});

btn = document.getElementById('animBtn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    animData.setDirection(1);
    animData.play();
});
```

In my assets folder i have a file called `data.json` and this is the file where `path:` in the above script should point to.
I can't seem to figure out how to use a file that's in my assets folder in the external js script.

Notes:

- `script.js` and `data.json` are in the same directory
- `script.js` gets called in a `blade.php` file

Comment: Have you referenced the external.js in the calling file?

Comment: To call the external js file I have done this in my blade: `<script src="{{ asset('script.js') }}"></script>`